# Can't switch HttpURLConnection method to POST

Tags: java, android

I am trying to send an HTTP POST request to a URL, using HttpsUrlConnection. here is what i am trying to do:

```
URL requestedUrl = null;
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null; 
try {
            requestedUrl = new URL("https://www.test.local/login/");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) requestedUrl.openConnection();

            try {
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            } catch (ProtocolException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(1500);

        try {
                urlConnection.connect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

When debugging i see that the RequestMethod remains GET, any idea why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `setDoOutput()` already sets the method to POST. You're doing it twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the given code you should not be able to see a request at all in your network trace.

In the given snippet you only open a connection via `urlConnection.connect()`, but you do not perform an actual request like with `urlConnection.getContent()`. The `connect()` method alone does not perform the request.

Replacing your last try-catch block with the following should send a POST request:

```
try {
    urlConnection.connect(); // open the connection
    urlConnection.getContent(); // send prepared request
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63249959/17492993)

In short the value shown as 'method' in the debugger is not what gets set by setRequestMethod("POST").

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).