# Can't set "POST" request to HttpURLConnection object

Tags: java, http

I'm going to connect satang api server with java.
In the following code con object can't set "POST" request.
I don't know the reason.
Please help me.

```
public String placeLimitOrder(String amount,String pair,String price,String side) throws IOException, BadResponseException
{
    Long lnonce=new Date().getTime();
    String nonce=lnonce.toString();
    String req="amount="+amount+"&nonce="+nonce+"&pair="+pair+"&price="+price+"&side="+side+"&type=limit";
    String operation="orders/?"+req;
    String signature=getSignature(req);
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    URL url = new URL(baseUrl+operation);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setDoOutput( true );
    con.setInstanceFollowRedirects( false );
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");

    con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "TDAX-API "+this.key);
    con.setRequestProperty("Signature",signature);
    con.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
    con.setRequestProperty( "charset", "utf-8");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "java client");
    con.setUseCaches( false );

    int responseCode=con.getResponseCode();
    if(responseCode!=HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
        System.out.println(con.getHeaderField("Allow"));
        throw new BadResponseException(responseCode);
    }
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

    String line;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(line);
    }
    rd.close();
    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: Any details? What is the result of your code execution? What do you mean when you say you can't?

Comment: int responseCode=con.getResponseCode();  At this line "responseCode" get 405 error.  While executing code, "con" object always having "GET" request.

Comment: 405 error means that the server restricts the method list available for the endpoint. It should supply `Allow` header where it lists the available methods for the endpoint. It is unlikely that `GET` method would be restricted. What is your `Allow` header value of the server response?

Comment: I ca'nt find the allow header. How can I find it?

Comment: Why are you setting `Content-Type` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, but not sending any content?

Comment: You seem to be trying to send your values using a query string, but there is no `?`. Your URL is `BASEURLorders/amount=X&nonce=X&pair=X&price=X&side=X&type=limit`. Do you have a handler for that URL? Perhaps you meant `BASEURLorders/?amount=X&nonce=X&pair=X&price=X&side=X&type=limit`

Comment: if insert "?", then got 500 error.

Comment: con.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");  This line doesn't have any influence for result.

Comment: @JoshColeen try to add `System.out.println(con.getHeaderField("Allow"));` as the first line of your `if` body

Comment: After insert above code, i got null.

Comment: @JoshColeen where exactly are u adding '?' sign?  can you update the code so that it now accounts the adivice of @Andreas?

Comment: Code updated. I've inserted    System.out.println(con.getHeaderField("Allow"));

Comment: "?" added. Then got 500 error.

Comment: @JoshColeen try `String operation="orders?"+req;` instead

Comment: If then , got 404 error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201920/discussion-between-josh-coleen-and-alexey-r).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've met same problem. 
I've solved this problem with following method.
First. Make your "Content-Type" to "application/json".
And parse the request params to your post body.

Answer (score 2):

You are not sending any data through your connection. [You have to use](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getOutputStream--):

```
con.getOutputStream().write(...);
```

where you shold send your POST request payload [as bytes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#write-byte:A-)

Comment: I had have this way, but it's same

Answer (score 2):

This is what I have found, I can't say with certainty it is the answer for everyone but hopefully it will shed some light on the problem for many others.

It seems that the internal "method" parameter of the HttpsURLConnection instance **IS NOT** very related to the requestMethod getter and setter on the instance. If you are like me you revert to using the debugger in android studio because logging in android is abysmal.
[image: Inspector vs. Evaluate Expression]
On the left I have the Debug inspector showing the contents of the URLConnection instance. On the right I have the results of "Evaluate Expression" on

```
connection.getRequestMethod() //right side of image
```

It is frustrating that there are not any definitive answers on this (or many other android questions) and when you try to find them you are often greeted with invitations to use someone else's library. This is not the ideal solution because in many cases using someone else's library requires security vetting.

Hopefully this helps. In my case, things were working correctly but the server was sending back a BAD_REQUEST response because of a bug over there.